# Python 3 - Pycrypto - Read only pinned buffer

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, pycrypto

So, I'm using Pycrypto to do some AES encryption and I am now porting my Python 2.7 code to Python 3.4. I am encoutering following error which I just cannot get my head around :

```
TypeError : argument must be read-only pinned buffer, not bytearray.
```

This occurs when I am trying to encrypt the content of a variable apparently. The exact line is :

```
token = b"\0" * 16
final_token = cipher.encrypt(token)
```

(token is obviously not 000... but i'm simplifying)

I have searched the internets for a solution and found that this error occured a lot in the websocket lib in python 2.6, but the solution (using memoryview(token) instead of token) doesn't help. Can someone explain what is happening there ? I am positively lost...

Comment: I got that, thanks ^^! Actually, I should probably rephrase the question : how do I build such a buffer from a bytearray ?

Comment: Sorry, that I didn't get your explanation, but I think my problem is ont knowing of these buffers. Tank you very much for the link, I'll read it and try `bytes()`. I'll get back to you and mark the question as answered if it works.

Comment: Well it worked, thank you very much ! And I even understand why.

Comment: There is an [open pull request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800972/python-3-pycrypto-read-only-pinned-buffer) for pycrypto to support bytearrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Pycrypto uses the encode method, it requires a [s# read-only buffer](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#strings-and-buffers). The buffer should not be resizeable, which isn't the case of `bytearray`. Such a buffer can be built by using the `bytes` function. Python 2 `str` was already immutable and so it was aceptable. The new line should be :

```
final_token = cipher.encrypt(bytes(token))
```

(all credits for this answer goes to @eryksun, see comments)